# Kendo grid event AFTER page change

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I want to subscribe to page change event in kendo grid:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').pager.bind('change', callback);
});
```

It is working in general, but my problem is that it is launched before the grid ui is refreshed. Is there any event/other way to know that the grid is refreshed/rerendered?

Comment: use the databound event http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that's working great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `change()` function, which will be fired after the Kendo grid page was changed:

```
element.kendoGrid({dataSource: {
                            transport: {
                                type: "jsonp",
                                read:
                                {
                                },

                            },
                            change: function(e) {
                                // PLACE YOUR CALLBACK CODE HERE

                                console.log(e);     
                            },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use the [`dataBound` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound):

```
var grid = $("#myKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBound", grid_dataBound);

function grid_dataBound(e) {
  console.log("dataBound");
}
```